# How to make two commands consume input from stdin sequentially?

Tags: shell

The following perl script `consume-10-lines-and-exit` reads ten lines from stdin and prints them. After that it exits.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

for (my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    my $line = <STDIN>;
    print $line;
}
```

I'm trying to combine `consume-10-lines-and-exit` and `cat` in such a way that the first ten lines of input and consumed and printed by the first command and then the rest are consumed by `cat`.

The following code few snippets all print 1 through 10 instead of 1 through 13 like I was expecting.

```
printf '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13' \
    | tr ' ' '\n' | { perl consume-10-lines-and-exit; cat; }

printf '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13' \
    | tr ' ' '\n' | ( perl consume-10-lines-and-exit; cat )

printf '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13' \
    | tr ' ' '\n' | sh -c 'perl consume-10-lines-and-exit; cat'
```

Is there a construction for sequencing commands so they will read input from stdin until they exit and then the next command will continue where the previous one left off?

Comment: Is it essential that `cat` not receive the first 10 lines? You could probably use something like `tee` if this isn't a hard requirement. Also, does your perl script have to exit, or could it stay in the path and handle passing the output you want to `cat`.

Comment: @csyria My question isn't so much about the perl script itself or cat, but about the shell's semantics. It seems like `cat` should be reading from the same stdin as the perl script in all of the above examples. I'm not sure why it isn't doing that and I'm wondering if there's a way to combine two commands so that they do read from the same stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that perl is using buffered input, so reads ahead beyond the lines you want to consume. Try this byte-by-byte version:

```
perl -e '
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => "all";
for (my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  my $line;
  while(sysread(*STDIN,my $char,1)==1){
      $line .= $char;
      last if $char eq "\n";
  }
  print $line;
}'
```

Comment: That's input file issue, not buffering.

Answer (score 3):

Using the grouping commands is right for doing this job, but the culprit is the input you put to the grouping commands, which is not seekable.

POSIX define in the [`INPUT FILE`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html) section that:

> When a standard utility reads a seekable input file and terminates
>   without an error before it reaches end-of-file, the utility shall
>   ensure that the file offset in the open file description is properly
>   positioned just past the last byte processed by the utility. For files
>   that are not seekable, the state of the file offset in the open file
>   description for that file is unspecified

`perl` is not a standard utility, but there's a big chance that it follow the standard spec. If you make your file seekable, then it will work:

```
$ seq 13 > /tmp/test
$ {perl -e 'for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){$line = <STDIN>;print $line}'; cat;} </tmp/test
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

If you don't want to use seekable file, you can force `perl` use lower layer that call system calls function `read()`, `write()`, `lseek()` for IO:

```
$ seq 13 | {
  PERLIO=:unix perl -e 'for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){$line = <STDIN>;print $line}'
  cat
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buffering might also be disabled by fiddling around with [PerlIO](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO) layers (see also [perlrun](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlrun.pod)). Also, that awkward and verbose C-style loop can be more easily written as `... for 1..10` or `for my $i (1..10) { ... }`.

```
$ perl -E 'say for 1..12' \
| ( PERLIO=:unix perl -e 'print "perl " . scalar <STDIN> for 1..10'; cat )
perl 1
perl 2
perl 3
perl 4
perl 5
perl 6
perl 7
perl 8
perl 9
perl 10
11
12
$
```

Comment: That's input file issue, not Perl IO.